# Ubuntu installation partitions don't match between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to change to Ubuntu. Currently, I am using Windows 10. Now I want to install Ubuntu with Windows 10, because a sudden change to Ubuntu may cause a problem to my work. So I plan to slowly change to Ubuntu - that's why I am installing Ubuntu with Windows 10.

While installing Ubuntu 17.10, in the partitioning screen, it shows the partitions like this

[image: Ubuntu partitioning screenshot]

but in my Windows 10 OS I have 3 partitions

- 215 GB (C drive with Windows)
- 162 GB (D drive with all my stuff)
- 87 GB (E drive with nothing) - I have separated this to install Ubuntu 
  in my drive.

This is my Windows Disk Management screenshot

[image: Windows Disk Management screenshot]

Can anyone help me to continue Ubuntu installation without losing my data and Windows OS?

Comment: So you're concerned because the partitions don't match between Ubuntu and Windows? You may want to edit the question title to clarify.

Comment: yes, updated my question title @WJAndrea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu installation problem with dynamic disks](https://askubuntu.com/q/910145/301745)