# Which partition is which? (Installation help)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, filesystem, windows-10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows on this new hard drive (not new but I never used it before).

Here's how I formatted the disk (from Windows disk management)

- Partition 1: 25GB
- Partition 2: 47.68 GB (this is where I want to install Ubuntu)
- Partition 3: .5 GB (Reserved)
- Partition 4: 49.43 GB (Windows 10 boot)
- Partition 5: 60GB
- Unallocated: 282 GB

(all are NTFS partitions)

However the Ubuntu install screen shows something like this:

- sdb1: 78GB (unknown)
- sdb2: 600MB (NTFS)
- sdb3: 53.1GB (NTFS)
- sdb4: 368.4GB (NTFS, according to Windows it is unallocated)

As you can see, it's nothing like what Windows shows.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Edit: The `lsblk` command returns this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   1.6G  0 loop /cdrom
loop1    7:1    0   1.5G  1 loop /rofs
loop2    7:2    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6350
loop3    7:3    0  19.3M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-budgie-welcome/92
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 152.8G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 192.3G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  78.2G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0    30G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0    10G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    25G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  46.9G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   579M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0  49.4G  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0  60.6G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   1  29.3G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1  29.3G  0 part /isodevice
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsblk` command from the Ubuntu live session (don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for pasted terminal text) and a screenshot of Windows disk management. I’m guessing you are using [Dynamic volumes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/basic-and-dynamic-disks#dynamic-disks) for Windows.

Comment: @Melebius thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with the info you wanted.

Comment: OK, so `sdb` seems to match your Windows layout. However, you seem to have another disk, `sda`? Do Windows show this disk? Have you selected the right disk in the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: Yup, I want to install on the second disk `sdb`

Comment: The `lsblk` command shows the correct disk layout, but for some reason the installer doesn't.

Comment: As suggested, you're probably using dynamic volumes for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Melebius and GabrielaGarcia. You guys are right. I was indeed using dynamic volumes for Windows. I just decided to create a new partition table from Ubuntu and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, Ubuntu can't be installed on "Dynamic disks". They can be converted to basic disks using a third-party partition manager.
See this question for more details:[Ubuntu installation problem with dynamic disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910145/ubuntu-installation-problem-with-dynamic-disks)

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you earned 15 [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have the reputation, don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: @Melebius done. This is a duplicate but I had no idea that Ubuntu can't be installed on "dynamic" disks when I posted this question. Thanks again!