# Second Hard Drive Problems

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

**EDIT:** Problem Solved. Apparently when I was using windows I turned on Fast Startup and Hibernation, I installed Windows again and turned them off and reinstall Ubuntu. Now I can write to Second Drive. Thank you everybody.

I was using windows and yesterday I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with burned USB, I erased the SSD completely and installed Ubuntu onto this drive. I also have HDD for storage. Everything is working fine. Only problem is I can not make a file or copy file from HDD now. I tried it in terminal but it said the HDD was read-only. Did I make a mistake when installing? Or is it something normal? I just found out this is the case with my SSD drive too (which Ubuntu is running) For more information: I use MSI GF63 Laptop and I have this 3 File Systems shown in my System Monitor application:

```
1) Device `/dev/nvme0n1p1` Directory `/boot/efi` Type `vfat` Total 535 MB 
2) Device `/dev/nvme0n1p2` Directory `/` Type `ext4` Total 125 GB 
3) Device `/dev/sda2` Directory `/media/myname/drivename` Type `fuseblk` Total 1TB
```

I think 2 and 3 are my C(SSD) and D(HDD). I don't know if any of my drives is mounted. Please you can ask any information if you need, I don't know much about what to provide here now. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help

When I write cat `/proc/mounts` in terminal, this is the result:

```
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3964648k,nr_inodes=991162,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=798952k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/bpf bpf rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18886 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tracefs /sys/kernel/tracing tracefs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop0 /snap/code/66 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop1 /snap/core/11167 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop3 /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop5 /snap/core18/2066 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop2 /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop6 /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop4 /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop7 /snap/snap-store/518 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop8 /snap/snap-store/542 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop9 /snap/snapd/11036 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop10 /snap/snapd/12057 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop11 /snap/core18/1988 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=798948k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/fuse /run/user/1000/doc fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
tmpfs /run/snapd/ns tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=798952k,mode=755 0 0
nsfs /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt nsfs rw 0 0
/dev/sda2 /media/myname/drivename fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

When I write `mount -o rw, remount/dev/sda2/media/myname/drivename`, this is the result:

```
mount: remount/dev/sda2/media/shamsiddin/Shamsiddin: can't find in /etc/fstab
```

**Edit**: The output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda2` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda2: 931.51 GiB, 1000186314752 bytes, 1953488896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda2p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/sda2p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/sda2p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/sda2p4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty
```

Comment: Did you disable "fast startup" in Windows?  If you have the hybrid suspend active it can interfere with your ability to mount file systems and other problems

Comment: Windows 10 has "fast startup" enabled by default. This hibernates the system install of a full shutdown. Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is running on my laptop

Comment: The command to remount is `sudo mount -o rw,remount /media/myname/drivename` where you only need to specify the mount name and not the device partition.  What is that drive formatted to?  What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`?

Comment: I added result of the command, what should I do now?

Comment: Those partitions showing Unknown will not be able to be mounted.  Something else formatted that drive.  Was that drive possibly done as a Dynamic drive in Windows?  If it was, Ubuntu cannot support that as it is a proprietary Microsoft thing.  See: https://askubuntu.com/a/910162/231142 but that would mean that it would have to be attached back to a Windows installation.

Comment: But my second hard drive (`dev/sda2`) is being mounted. I can read the content, videos inside it. I  just can't write to it. Can second hard drive be a Microsoft thing? Does it mean I can not use my second drive in Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you try the exact command I gave above for the remount?  The command you have in your question is incorrect.  Anytime I have ever needed to remount a drive to rw it is always done in the format of `sudo mount -o rw,remount <mount name>`, there is no need to specify the `/dev/sda` at all.  Also, you have not answered the question of where that drive came from.  Were you using it in Windows and maybe upgraded it to a Dynamic Disk?  Also, Ubuntu / Linux cannot write to an unknown partition type as it does not have the code in it to support how to write to it.

Comment: Do not use NTFS without having Windows. Use ext4. If you can read your data, backup it up & totally repartition & reformat partition(s) to ext4 (or other Linux format). Make sure you keep it as gpt partitioned, not MBR(msdos). If NTFS, you have to periodically repair it with chkdsk and it will eventually need defrag. Those commands are only in Windows and cannot be run from Linux.

Comment: Try `sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sda2`, then `reboot`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you solved your problem. Please don't put the solution inside the question. Please click on the **Answer your own question** button below and write the solution as an answer. Then after the required waiting time accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check button ✓ and turn it green ✅. This will help others. See the site help for how to answer questions in this site.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Disks` and look to confirm the details about the drive (and whether it's mounted)

[image]

In terminal:

```
sudo chown myname:myname /media/myname/drivename
```

You can add a line to `/etc/fstab` if its not being mounted automatically using the UUID such as (using my example)

```
UUID=6f71cdf1-61c9-404c-9535-a917b6febf7b /media/graham/STORAGE ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: I added some more information after trying your solution, can you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before I get to your main question it might be useful to know that actually both the 1) and 2) partitions are in fact referring to your NVMe drive (nvme0). You can determine this by looking at the device names both refer to nvme0 however one refers to the first partition (p1) and the other to the second partition (p2).

In short, the first partition is a small system partition containing the bootloader for the rest of the operating system which contains among other things the necessary filesystem driver to read the main ext4 filesystem containing the root filesystem.

That bit of trivia aside back to your main question. From what you have said it seems possible that your second hard drive (/dev/sda2) may be mounted as read-only for some reason.

You can use the following command to attempt to fix this, be sure to replace /media/myname/drivename with the actual path:

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda2 /media/myname/drivename
```

If that does not work then we may need more information to try and diagnose your problem further if you can add the output of the following command to your question it may help:

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

This should help us to determine if any other mount options are causing the issue somehow.

**Edit:**
The reason that your mount command is not working is that you made a few typing mistakes with your spaces. The spacing is required as they are separate arguments and the spaces tell mount where each argument begins and ends. I recommend trying the command again but take care to copy the spaces exactly as in the following example or you can simply try copying and pasting this one.

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda2 /media/shamsiddin/Shamsiddin
```

That should do it although I did also forget to mention that if you get a permission denied error when you run the command you may need to run the command using sudo as follows:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda2 /media/shamsiddin/Shamsiddin
```

Hopefully, that will resolve your problem but if it doesn't then the resulting error message should be enlightening at least. Let us know how you get on and if the problem isn't solved please be sure to copy any error messages you get and add them to your question.

Comment: I added more information after trying your solution, can you figure out the problem?

Comment: `mount: /media/shamsiddin/Shamsiddin: mount point not mounted or bad option.`
I am getting this kind of error. what should I do in this case? Thank you for your help